# The distribution of observed unique objects, given the previous number of observed unique objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have N unique objects, where N is known, but I have a subsample of only M of them in a bag, where M is unknown. I draw X from the bag with replacement (where X is known) and observe A unique objects (where A is known). If I next draw Y from the bag with replacement (where Y is known) what is the distribution for B, where B is the number of unique objects I will observe?

Comment: Are you able to give a distribution for $M$ (given $N$) before the draw of $X$?

Comment: I have no information about M, so I suppose a uniform prior over [1, N] would make sense, if that's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you can use Bayesian techniques.

If you draw items $x$ times uniformly with replacement from $m$ items, the probability of seeing $A=a$ different items is

$$\mathbb P_{m,x}(A=a) = \frac{m! \, S_2(x,a)}{(m-a)!\, m^x}$$ where $S_2(m,k)$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), at least when $1\le a\le m$ and $1 \le a \le x$.

In a comment you have suggested a prior distribution for $M$ of a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ so $\pi_0(n)=\frac{1}{n}$.  This would then suggest, conditioned on observing $A=a$ different items when drawing items $x$ times uniformly with replacement, a posterior distribution for $M$ of

$$ \pi(M=m \mid x, A=a) =\frac{ \frac1n\mathbb P_{m,x}(A=a)}{\sum\limits_{w=a}^n\frac1n\mathbb P_{w,x}(A=a)} =\frac{ \frac{m! }{(m-a)!\, m^x}}{\sum\limits_{w=a}^n\frac{w! }{(w-a)!\, w^x}} $$

for $a\le m\le n$, though you could not cancel the $\frac1n$ term if $M$ had a different prior distribution, though you could still cancel the $S_2(x,a)$ term.

This in turn would suggest a predictive distribution for $B$ the number of different items seen when drawing a further $y$ times uniformly with replacement of $$\mathbb P_{y}(B=b \mid x, A=a)= \sum\limits_{m=\max(a,b)}^n\pi(M=m \mid x, A=a) \, \mathbb P_{m,y}(B=b) \\ = S_2(y,b) \frac{ \sum\limits_{m=\max(a,b)}^n \frac{(m!)^2 }{(m-a)!(m-b)!\, m^{x+y}}}{\sum\limits_{w=a}^n\frac{w! }{(w-a)!\, w^x}} \,  .$$

This is not particularly attractive to work with but here is an example: suppose $n=10, x=5, a=3, y=8$; then I think you may get something like the following probabilities for $B=b$:

```
 b   probs
 1 0.0001075841
 2 0.0296185176
 3 0.2870405735
 4 0.3030199248
 5 0.2360570167
 6 0.1157040838
 7 0.0265781490
 8 0.0018741506
```

and the fact these add up to $1$ slightly increases the likelihood that I have not made a substantial error.